# Center play button on top of poster image in Podlove Web Player

Tags: css, z-index, tailwind-css

I want to display a very basic template (only play button and a poster image) for a Podlove Web Player. The basic code is something like this ([Docs](https://docs.podlove.org/podlove-web-player/v5/templating/components/poster)), but it displays the button to the right of the poster image:

```
<root class="flex">
  <poster></poster>
  <play-button></play-button>
</root>
```

*Edit*: I managed to show the button on top of the image and vertically centered, but it's still squeezed to the left edge.

```
<root>
  <poster class="w-full"></poster>
  <play-button class="absolute inset-0"></play-button>
</root>
```

How can I display the button on top of the poster image and center it?

Podlove uses Tailwind CSS, which I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as intended:

```
<root class="flex justify-center">
  <poster class="w-full"></poster>
  <play-button class="absolute self-center"></play-button>
</root>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" integrity="sha512-wnea99uKIC3TJF7v4eKk4Y+lMz2Mklv18+r4na2Gn1abDRPPOeef95xTzdwGD9e6zXJBteMIhZ1+68QC5byJZw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<root class="p-4 flex justify-center">
  <poster id="poster" class="relative h-40 w-56 rounded bg-blue-700">
    <!-- Play Button -->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="absolute text-white top-1/2 left-1/2 h-10 w-10 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 transform cursor-pointer" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5">
      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M14.752 11.168l-3.197-2.132A1 1 0 0010 9.87v4.263a1 1 0 001.555.832l3.197-2.132a1 1 0 000-1.664z" />
      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
    </svg>
  </poster>
</root>
```

Or, using the original Podlovers Components:

```html
<root class="p-4 flex justify-center">
  <poster id="poster" class="relative h-48 w-48">
    <play-button variant="simple" class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 transform" />
  </poster>
</root>
```

The other solutions suggests absolutely centering the play button within the `root` element. This might not be what you want, as the button will not be centered relative to the player. Moving the player, e.g. by adding another element, would stop the play button from being centered.